# primefaces fileupload doesn't work in ie8

Tags: primefaces

The problem occurs in IE8, after we click the upload button it just hangs and progress bar doesn't go away, but it works fine in Firefox. I'm using PrimeFaces 4.0 and JSF 2.0

```
<p:fileUpload id="getCompElementComponentId" label="Browse"                                                                                                            fileUploadListener="#{applicationAction.addUpload}"                                                                                                            
mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false" multiple="true"
sizeLimit="52489260" fileLimit="30"                                                                                                                
allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(jpg|doc|docx|txt|xls|xlsx|pdf|gif|rtf)$/">
</p:fileUpload>
```

Thanks, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

This post can provide you some information on your problem
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036655/primefaces-pfileupload-doesnt-work-in-ie-10)

Turning on the `multiple=true` is known to cause problem in certain browsers and IE is one of them. But turning of `multiple=false` works perfect in IE 8. See below code

```
<p:fileUpload mode="advanced" multiple="false" auto="true" id="Object__Attachment__Location" 
        fileUploadListener="#{fileHandlingManagedBean.upload}" immediate="true" 
        label="Browse &amp; Upload" required="true" requiredMessage="#{dictionary['Common.AttachmentNotFound']}" 
        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(doc|docx|xls|jpg|msg|csv|pps|ppt|xml|mng|bmp|gif|jpeg|txt|pdf|midi|wma|css|zip|rar|rtf|png)$/" 
        invalidFileMessage="Please Attach a valid file" 
        widgetVar="Object__Attachment__Location_WidgetVar" >
</p:fileUpload>
```

But if you really need to upload multiple file then you need to handle it with your custom implementation.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried changing it to multiple="false", but it didn't help. Even the fileUpload on Primefaces Showcase in IE 8 has the same behavior

Comment: The fileUpload is placed inside a h:form which is part of p:dialog like this

Comment: Here is the behavior I noticed, p:fileUpload is placed inside a h:form which is part of p:dialog. So if I remove the h:form then it does closes the progress bar but then file is not uploaded i.e. its not calling the fileUploadListener="#applicationAction.addUpload}". But when have the h:form, then it uploads the file but doesn't closes the progress bar